# Sql binding in Spring throws org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc

Im making Spring MVC web application. For database access I'm using SQL binding. Everything was running good yesterday but I suddenly encountered `UnableToExecuteStatementException` when I tried to edit user data from my web app.

This is code where I've errors as per stacktrace.

```
public String editUser (UserDto objUserDto) {       
    Handle objHandle = objBaseService.getHandle();
        objHandle.createStatement("UPDATE USER set email = :email," +
                                 "userTypeId = :userTypeId," +
                                 "userName = :userName," +
                                 "trackingInterval = :trackingInterval," +
                                 "enableWebCam = :enableWebCam," +
                                 "showCaptureInfo = :showCaptureInfo," +
                                 "showSeverInfo = :showServerInfo," +
                                 "autoLogin = :autoLogin," +
                                 "remarks = :remarks WHERE userId = :userId")
                .bind("email", objUserDto.getEmail())
                .bind("userTypeId", objUserDto.getUserTypeId())
                .bind("userName", objUserDto.getUserName())
                .bind("trackingInterval", objUserDto.getTrackingInterval())
                .bind("enableWebCam", objUserDto.getEnableWebCam())
                .bind("showCaptureInfo", objUserDto.getShowCaptureInfo())
                .bind("showServerInfo", objUserDto.getShowServerInfo())
                .bind("autoLogin", objUserDto.getAutoLogin())
                .bind("remarks", objUserDto.getRemarks())
                .bind("userId", objUserDto.getUserId())
                .execute();      //UserService.java:106
                return "success";   
}
```

And UserController edit function just calling UserService.

```
public UserService objUserService;
String userResult = objUserService.editUser(objUserDto);//(UserController.java:111)
```

And stacktrace is:

```
org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'showSeverInfo' in 'field list'
at org.skife.jdbi.v2.SQLStatement.internalExecute(SQLStatement.java:873)
at org.skife.jdbi.v2.Update.execute(Update.java:51)
at com.isa.tt.service.UserService.editUser(UserService.java:106)
at com.isa.tt.controller.UserController.updateUser(UserController.java:111)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:774)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
```

Its confusing cause I have shpwServerInfo column in my database.
[image: serverInfo]

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception says it, 
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column `showSeverInfo` in field list.
Please make sure that the field `showSeverInfo` exists in the table `USER`

Comment: I already checked that and I do have showSeverInfo column in my database table. And that's what confused me most.

Comment: Your query uses "showSeverInfo = :showServerInfo,", correct that, and try again

Comment: I solved that  already. I feel so dumb making that mistake.Got to say You really got good observation though.